# registerProtocolHandler and ServiceWorker

Tags: javascript, service-worker

is it possible to register custom protocol in ServiceWorker. I mean using registerProtocolHandler or anything else? My server returning custom protocol that my js app need to handle this?

Comment: Do you mean other than `http` or `https`?

Comment: @Salva yes for sure :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible. Per specification, only `http` and `https` will be intercepted ([step 9 in Main fetch](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#main-fetch)).